# delete causes core dumped, and why?

Tags: c++, c++11, delete-operator

I encountered core dump when delete the array new without delete[]

here is my code:

```
Page *p;
p = new Page[10];
delete p;
```

but when I try to delete int[], there seems nothing

here:

```
int *p;
p = new int[10];
delete p;
```

I want to know why the first example causes the core dump but the second runs perfectly?

This is my calss.

```
class Page {
public:    
    Page() {
        page_id_ = INVALID_PAGE_ID;
        pin_count_ = 0;
        is_dirty_ = 0;
        reset_mem();
    }

    ...
private:
    void reset_mem() { memset(data_, 0, PAGE_SIZE); }

    std::atomic<page_id_t> page_id_;
    std::atomic<int> pin_count_;
    std::atomic<bool> is_dirty_;
    std::atomic<lsn_t> lsn_;

    char data_[PAGE_SIZE];

    ReaderWriterLatch latch_;
};
```

Thank You!

Comment: By not using `delete[]` your program has undefined behavior, i.e., a bug. "Runs perfectly" is one of the possible outcomes of undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `delete` rather than `delete[]` on a pointer allocated with `new[]` exhibits undefined behavior. "Seems to work" is one possible manifestation of undefined behavior; "program crashed" is another.

Practically speaking, the reason for the difference in behavior on a typical implementation is this. For an array of class type, `delete[]` needs to run destructors on all elements of the array. However, it's only given a pointer to the first element, but not the size. To make it work, `new[]` would allocate more memory than needed for the array itself, write the size of the array at the beginning of that memory, and hand out the pointer offset past this length indicator. In effect, the array length is stored at the negative offset from the returned pointer, before the first element of the array.

`delete[]` would then read the size prefix from the negative offset, run destructors, then offset the pointer backward so that it points to the actual beginning of the allocated memory block, and pass this adjusted pointer to the heap manager's deallocation routine (e.g. `free()`).

But when you pass this pointer to plain `delete`, it wouldn't know to adjust it backward, and would pass it to `free()` (or similar) as-is. The end result is similar to

```
char* p = (char*)malloc(256);
free(p + 16);
```

It should be obvious why this is a problem.

For an array of non-class type, and perhaps also a trivially-destructible class type, `new[]` doesn't allocate extra memory or adjust the pointer, and `delete[]` doesn't perform any adjustments either. For such types, `delete[]` is equivalent to `delete`.

Comment: Qualify that last sentence; it is still UB.